# start /b javaw with custom path to java home issue

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm writing a windows batch script to start my Java program in the background, using javaw.

The issue comes when I let the user have a custom path to the Java Home. Let's say in an example when the path to Java home is: `C:\Users\Sample User\Desktop\java` (notice the space in the path), when I try running the start command, it breaks because of the spaces.

Example:

```
@echo off
set CUSTOM_JAVA_HOME=C:\Users\Federico Einhorn\Desktop\java

set CP=myjar.jar;../lib/*;.
set JAVA_PARAMS=-myOption -Xmx1024M -classpath %CP%
set JAVA_CLASS=com.myorg.MyClass
set RUN_OPTS=%JAVA_PARAMS% %JAVA_CLASS% start

start /b "%CUSTOM_JAVA_HOME%/bin/javaw" %RUN_OPTS%
```

That `start` command fails as the `CUSTOM_JAVA_HOME` has spaces.

> Windows cannot find '-myOption'. Make sure you typed the name
>   correctly, and then try again.

This doesn't happen when I run my jar with regular java:

`"%CUSTOM_JAVA_HOME%/bin/java" %RUN_OPTS%`

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: You should use a backslash, not a forward slash: `"%CUSTOM_JAVA_HOME%/bin/javaw"` should be `"%CUSTOM_JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw"` and `set CP=myjar.jar;../lib/*` should be `set CP=myjar.jar;..\lib\*;`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name using backslashes doesn't solve it. I still get the same error.

Comment: That's because `Start` sees `"%CUSTOM_JAVA_HOME%/bin/javaw"` as a title. The fix is to include a title yourself, _even a blank one_: `Start "" /B "%CUSTOM_JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw" %RUN_OPTS%`

Comment: @Compo that worked!! Asweome. You should put that comment as the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Start` sees `"%CUSTOM_JAVA_HOME%/bin/javaw"` as a title.

The fix is to include a title yourself, even a blank one:

```
Start "" /B "%CUSTOM_JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw" %RUN_OPTS%
```